# Kaobook not compiling (anywhere)

Tags: compiling, overleaf, tufte, kaobook

I am trying to compile the most basic file of the Kaobook template as provided [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) and it does not work.

Now, on my TeXLive, it doesn't because it gives me in the report that it is missing an options.sty file (an issue that I do not really know how to fix).

What is more peculiar is that this is not compiling on Overleaf either (and I am literally opening the file there from the option provided on the page linked above without modifying anything).

Is there any specific reason?

Any feedback will be most welcome!

Comment: About options.sty: I'd contact the author, as this style isn't inside the v1.3.zip file. CORRECTION: options.tex is inside /chapters (but it's not a style, just documentation) // Just to make sure: did you follow ch. "1.4 How to Use This Class" in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the immediate reply. I did read it and tried – without success – to implement it. However, by specifying that the compiling process does not work on Overleaf either, I wanted to point out that maybe the problem runs deeper, since Overleaf should make the process work no matter what, right? (and, btw, it's not a rethorical question: I gave for granted it is so, but I am not actually sure about it.)

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to check if somebody else has the same problem in compiling the template on Overleaf.

Comment: Ok. Again, the `options.sty` is missing in the zip-file. The best way would be to contact the author.

Comment: Looking at the repository at https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook, there is no `option.sty` file, but neither is any call to load `options.sty` in the code...

Comment: I just tried to compile the example in Overleaf, and it works ok for me (with a bit of warnings, but no error). (tried both with TeXLive 2022 and 2023).

Comment: ...and also, downloading the zip from overlaf and compiling locally works ok (TeXLive 2023). You must have some stray local file that is loaded before the distribution one.

Comment: Great (in general – not so great for me)! But shouldn't it work on Overleaf no matter what (i.e., beyond the specs that somebody has on their computer)?

Comment: @Kolmin the problem is that I can't reproduce your problem, even on overleaf. If I click on the link you provided: https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=https://www.latextemplates.com/actions/action_download_template?template=kaobook-overleaf ,  the overleaf project compiles without errors, so I can't know what's wrong with your setup. You probably added something, or changed something, or you are using some legacy versions of some package... but if you can't provide an example that's failing for me, I can't help... sorry.

Comment: @Rmano: Yep, that I understand. However, what I was wondering is if Overleaf is the same for everybody (which is what I thought, since we do not have to download or install anything), because, if it is, this problem should not arise at all and that should compile on Overleaf for me as well.

Comment: That's why I tried to compile on Overleaf in the very first place: because I thought that – somewhat (I am expressing myself very informally) – it employs the same overall system for all the users, contrary to the various MikTex or TekLive that change from one year (and update) to another for every user, given their specific preferences.

Comment: You are not saying what you are actually using on overleaf. Overleaf has lots of options, e.g. you can change the tex system and the engine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot! Now, I see. Sorry, this was a point I completely missed (my – huge – bad).

Comment: @Kolmin, is it solved now?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. :(